# F2PY: wrapping a Fortran subroutine which uses fortran modules

Tags: python, fortran, f2py, interfacing

I have a legacy code in Fortran for creation of `FDq-matrices`. The code consists of a subroutine, which I would like to be able to call in Python. This subroutine itself uses Fortran modules.

Subroutine which I need to call from Python:

- finiteDifferences.f90

Modules used within subroutine:

- Lagrange_Interpolation_Method.f
- Linear_Algebra_Lapack.f
- Nonlinear_Algebra.f
- Piecewise_Polynomial_Interpolation.f
- Optimum_Grid_Methods.f

Ideally, I would like to end up with an `fdq.so` file which I could import into my python code.

I am perfectly capable of using `F2PY` to create `.so` file from a single subroutine, even including Lapack. But I don't know how to work with subroutines which call for modules.

For simple compilation I add a program `main.f90` which calls the subroutine and I use following command:

```
gfortran -O3 -o fdq -fcheck=all -ffree-form -fdefault-double-8 -fdefault-real-8 -framework Accelerate -Wall Lagrange_Interpolation_Method.f90 Nonlinear_Algebra.f90 Linear_Algebra_Lapack.f90 Piecewise_Polynomial_Interpolation.f90 Optimum_Grid_Methods.f90 finiteDifferences.f90 main.f90
```

Then when calling for F2PY with following command:

```
f2py3 -c --verbose --opt='-O3 -fcheck=all -ffree-form -fdefault-double-8 -fdefault-real-8 -framework Accelerate' Lagrange_Interpolation_Method.f90 Nonlinear_Algebra.f90 Linear_Algebra_Lapack.f90 Piecewise_Polynomial_Interpolation.f90 Optimum_Grid_Methods.f90 finiteDifferences.f90 -m fdq
```

The first error produced by the above command:

```
/var/folders/bj/4qqzkp4560d75dw4wr7tpmr00000gn/T/tmp39eelon3/src.macosx-13-arm64-3.11/fdqmodule.c:578:23: error: expected expression nodes_Dims[0]=1 + ; ^
```

Comment: What is your problem? Is there anything wrong when you run the command you show at the end? Does the compilation finish or are there anu error messages? Are what you call "modules" actual Fortran modules or just source files with external procedures?

Comment: The modules are actual Fortran modules. The first error which is given after using the last command is:  /var/folders/bj/4qqzkp4560d75dw4wr7tpmr00000gn/T/tmp39eelon3/src.macosx-13-arm64-3.11/fdqmodule.c:578:23: error: expected expression
    nodes_Dims[0]=1 + ;
                      ^

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that it is a syntax error in the .c file created by the F2PY?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the description of the errors. Do not use comments for such information, they can be short-lived. Yes, I think it is an error in the produced C file.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any suggestions or ideas where this error is coming from? Fortran side, or do I have to change my compilation commands?

Comment: f2py is old, buggy, and does not support complete Fortran. Without the code we cannot say which part causes the problem. Perhaps one could just link with pre-compiled .o files instead of putting everything into f2py.

Comment: I'm not sure because I almost do not use Python, let alone calling Fortran from Python, but I think the other way is to write a wrapper on the Fortran side to prepare calling it from C, and on the Python side use the usual techniques to call C code.

Comment: @PierU Thank you for the recommendations. Unfortunately, I am not proficient with C and I don't want to spend massive amounts of time on this issue atm. I'll go on for now with interfacing via textfiles and put this on "low-heat" for now :D

Comment: Actually this solution doesn't require any C code between Python and Fortran.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава I tried that, but it also didn't work. I also tried f90wrap https://github.com/jameskermode/f90wrap, but not much difference. As I said in the previous comment. Will leave it for later time...

Comment: @PierU is that the iso-c-bindings approach? I have done that yet

Comment: Yes, you should use `iso_c_binding` for that